# Left shift operator

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

If I have the following:

```
char v = 32; // 0010 0000
```

then I do:

```
v << 2
```

the number becames negative. // 1000 0000 -128

I read the standard but it is only written:

> If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2 E2 is
>   representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned.

so I don't understand if is a rule that if a bit goes on most left bit the
number must begin negative.

I'm using GCC.

Comment: Shifting it twice gives you `1000 0000`, and the first bit is the sign bit.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour,  printf("%d\n", (char)(v << 2));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left shifting it twice would give 1000 0000)<sub>2</sub> = 128)<sub>10</sub>.

If 128 is representable in `char` i.e. you're in some machine (with a supporting compiler) that provides a `char` of size > 8 bits then 128 would be the value you get (since it's representable in such a type).

Otherwise, if the size of a `char` is just 8 bits like most common machines, for a signed character type that uses two's complement for negative values, [-128, 127] is the representable range. You're in undefined behaviour land since it's not representable as-is in that type.

Comment: But if [-128, 127] is the representable range why am I in undefined behaviour. It seems as GCC put the correct results because the char is in that range.

Comment: @xdevel2000: E1 × 2^E2 means the mathematical correct result, not a bit-shift.

Comment: I think you're confusing mathematics with computer representation. Ignore, for a moment that we're doing this on a CPU. If you left shift manually 00100000 you'd get 10000000. What is the value of this number in decimal system, 128. Now coming to the computer representation of 128, is it possible to represent it in 8 bits? Yes, but only if all 8 bits are available for representation i.e. only on `unsigned char`.

Comment: On a `signed char` or `char`, out of 256 states you can represent using 8 bits, you've to divide it into 2 for positive and negative, so 128 +ve and 128 -ve states, but hey, what about 0? if you accommodate 0 in +ve states, you've one less for +ve numbers hence [-128, 127]; in this range 128 is not representable.

Answer (score 1):

Signed data primitives like **char** use two's complement(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement) to encode value. You probably are looking for is **unsigned char** which won't encode the value using two's complement(no negatives).

Comment: Then it should work, when the shift was only 1, correct?

Comment: The standard doesn't require signed types to be implemented as two's complement. A cast to a corresponding unsigned type, however, yields a signed value's two's complement representation.

Comment: @ViktorLexington yes, if the shift was only once, then it's still well-defined and the result would be 64.

Comment: Well, yes the number will still be positive if the shift is one, but it's not like it didn't work because the shift was 2. When working with signed data types the compiler(GCC in this case) will intrinsically generate assembly that coincides with signed arithmetic(and comparators). A good example of this would be that if both numbers are signed the expression (-1 < 0) compiled in GCC would be true, while if 0 was unsigned it would be false(since GCC would use an unsigned comparison instruction that would interpret the bits that encode -1 as a unsigned positive number, not a signed number).

Answer (score 0):

Try using unsigned char instead char uses less bit for representing your character, by using unsigned char you avail more bits for representing your character

```
unsigned char var=32;
v=var<<2;
```